# Why am I seeing stagnant water inside the shower drainage pipe hole?

Tags: shower, drainage, pipe

I was cleaning the shower drainage pipe (removing hair etc) in the upstairs bathroom and I can see water around 1 foot deep. See the pic.[image]

Is that normal? Shouldn't the pipe be empty? If water stays stagnant like that, it can't be good.

If this is a problem, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes it's normal and what you want. It's called a P-trap and the water sitting in there seals out the sewer gasses.

My ASCII P-trap:

```
                  \ /
                  | |
   __________     | |
   _________ \    / /
            \*\__/*/
             \****/
              ----
```

The asterisks would be the water that forms the stopper.

In an empty home or in drains that are infrequently used (such as a basement) you these traps can eventually dry out from evaporation and let sewer gasses seep in.

In your case, if you aren't going to use the shower for months on end, I suppose you could add a drop of bleach to the drain. If the shower is used semi-regularly, there should be no issues at all.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You answered exactly what I was asking for. Before I accept, one question I have is that there are a few baths and sinks that I don't use for months together. Is it advisable to open the tap once in a while or how is the bleach going to help?

Comment: The bleach suggestion was in case you were worried about grime/slime sitting in there. As for baths/sinks you don't use for months at a time, it certainly wouldn't hurt to turn the tap on for a minute once a month or so. As to whether or not they'd actually dry out in that time would depend on your climate/humidity.

Comment: what will happen if they dry out.. is it certain that the sewer gases will seep into the house? any problem apart from a potential smell?

Comment: You'd notice the smell long before any potential other issues (of which I can't really think of any...I guess I wouldn't light up a smoke in a closed bathroom full of sewer gas, I suppose)

Answer (score 1):

You can get small sewer flies if drains not used for a while easy to eradicate just put bleach down drain every month, leave overnight they are harmless but not nice to have in your home

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.